# how to show latitude and longitude instantly in android?

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to show the current address location using gps in android,but I am not able to show the current location's latitude and longitude values instantly.Its taking almost one to five minutes to show the address, by then my application is getting lower performance,i would like to increase the performance of my application,can anyone tell me how to overcome this issue.
or 
Is there any ways to get that latitude and longitude values faster.

Suggestions please

Thanks for your precious time!..

Please find my source for reference

```
public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

Button btnShowLocation;

// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

    // show location button click event
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {        
            // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

            // check if GPS enabled     
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                // \n is for new line
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                System.out.println("Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude);
            }else{
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }}});   }}
```

**GPSTracker.java**

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}}
```

Comment: Without the code to `GpsTracker`, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: @CommonsWare please visit my question again i have included the GPSTracker.java for reference

Comment: Never never never never never instantiate a `Service` directly.

Comment: @CommonsWare then can you please tell me how to use the service indirectly or alternate solutions

Comment: Start by deleting `extends Service`. What you have is a generic helper class, nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

Until the GPS acquires a fix, you can't get an accurate location. It may take seconds and it may take minutes, it depends on the device and the environment settings (Location, weather, under the sky/inside building, etc...).

If you want to get a coarse location faster, you can get the location using `NETWORK_PROVIDER`, which isn't that accurate but can get you the location faster.

And if an immedate location is a must, you can use [`getLastKnownLocation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29), which is not as reliable as waiting for a location update, but it may help (If it's not really outdated).

(This answer does not refer to your `GpsTracker` class, whose code we don't know. But it shouldn't matter.)

Comment: Please visit my question again i've included the GPSTracker.java for reference

Comment: This class is just wrong... It's a service and you are instantiating it, not starting, and it doesn't do *anything* with the location updaets it requests (`onLocationChanged` is empty). Don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

@manick start a service by using startservice(), you can access the values in service class in your main activity by IBinder (here appservicebindobj ) by the establishing serviceconnection() .. dont instantiate service... this code may help you..

```
     public ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

     public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
      appservicebindobj = ((com.services.AppService.MyBinder) binder).getService();

      Toast.makeText(UserActivity.this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

     public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
         Toast.makeText(UserActivity.this, "NotConnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      appservicebindobj = null;
    }
   };



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    unbindService(mConnection);

    super.onPause();

}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 bindService(new Intent(this, com.services.AppService.class),       mConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    super.onResume();
}`
```